# Fine-grained Google OAuth Scope

Tags: oauth, scope, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

Being a privacy paranoid, this is something I can't seem to find via Google OAuth2 document - **can I only request the email address and user identifer**?

I recall there is a time where I can get both email address and user identifer just by using

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
```

Now it seems without `userinfo.profile`, google only return user email address. I don't need anything other than user identifer from the profile scope though... To me it's a waste and requesting profile permission (access to birthday/location) may trigger unnecessary privacy concerns (well, to me anyway.)

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
```

Does requesting Google user identifer = getting `userinfo.profile` permission?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you may request only the user_ID

The currently supported way is to add scope https//www.googleapis. com/auth/plus.me

In the future we will also support 'openid'  for that purpose but that will also cause the server to return OpenIDConnect compliant responses and since that standard is still not finalized using it now exposes you to backwards incompatible API changes.

Comment: Great, so there is a way. just wondering if 'plus.me' is a stable api yet? I find it in various google+ document but not in the main google oauth doc, what does 'plus.me' entails in terms of permissions ('associate with your g+ profile'), I see it only return ID as you mentioned.

Comment: just to answer my own question, even for google account that does not have g+ profile, it returns the correct id. but further request on https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me will return 404 not found if this user do not own g+ profile

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'll need the `userinfo.profile` scope to get anything more than an email address, confirmation that the address is verified and hd on Google Apps user accounts (hd attribute let's you know it's a Google Apps account, not consumer). Those 3 attributes are all that's returned by `userinfo.email`.